# any reason to whitelist data from user input when updating/creating a model in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I find myself doing this before I create or save a user:

```
 var data = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'name', 'username', 'title');
```

But I don't know if its really necessary. For example, what happens if someone sends in `salt` or `hashedPassword` or any attribute that the model doesn't support. Does it just get thrown away?

`salt` and `hashedPassword` are virtual attributes on my schema.

It seems like it could be dangerous by not whitelisting assuming someone sent in a json object that contained other dynamic attributes, like `followers: ['fake1', 'fake2']` etc. Which would completely override what has been added previously, if I understand this correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule of thumb in web development is to always sanitize the input.

That being said, Mongoose has an option [strict](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict):

> The strict option, ensures that values passed to
>   our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get
>   saved to the db.

In Mongoose 2.x default value for strict was false, but in 3.x strict option is now set to true by defult.

You can specify it on your schema:

```
new Schema({ .. }, { strict: true })
```

You can also overwrite it on your model:

```
var Thing = db.model('Thing');
var thing = new Thing(doc, true);  // enables strict mode
```

Virtual properties will never be overwritten by the data that you supply into your model. It's because the way that Mongoose is internally storing virtual properties.

Each property in the schema has its type defined (virtual property has VirtualType). Virtual properties are internally stored in a different object than "real" properties.

When you're accessing the virtual property Mongoose will check the property type and call the getter for that property type (basically, call the function you defined for virtual property).

Comment: Thanks. I'm on 3.6 so I guess its on by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `data` only contains the properties you listed in `pick`. If your `req.body` has other fields it would not be in `data`.

For the overriding part that depends on how you are doing it. In native mongodb driver the API calls are different for insert and update. And updating also differentiates overwriting entire entry (with `$set`) or just a field. But in mongoose a simple top-level update does replace entire document. So if you are using this and want to limit entries, yes. You can read it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html).

But still it is always good idea to check what you are going to store in the database. `pick` is entirely for weeding unwanted data.

Comment: I have a different api method that manages the `user.followers` array. I wanted to avoid having someone send in their own `followers` list in `req.body.followers` and completely overwrite what the db has.